# Iptables: how to easily group rules in chain?

Tags: routes, iptables, netfilter, chain

I have some netfilter rules like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE -p udp --dport 4444
iptables -t mangle -I INPUT -j MARK --set-mark 100 -p udp --dport 4444
iptables -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE -p udp --sport 4444
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -j MARK --set-mark 200 -p udp --sport 4444
```

I need a simple way to group this rules, aim to delete them all together, like this

```
iptables -N MYCHAIN

iptables -I MYCHAIN -j NFQUEUE -p udp --dport 4444
iptables -t mangle -I MYCHAIN -j MARK --set-mark 100 -p udp --dport 4444
iptables -I MYCHAIN -j NFQUEUE -p udp --sport 4444
iptables -t mangle -I MYCHAIN -j MARK --set-mark 200 -p udp --sport 4444

# Fast deleting
iptables -F MYCHAIN 
iptables -X MYCHAIN
```

But it doesn't works, surely i have to connect default chain with MYCHAIN, but i don't figure how. Are there better or simpler solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Chains exist only in one table. If you run `iptables -N MYCHAIN`, you are creating `MYCHAIN` in the filter table. If you want to use `MYCHAIN` in the mangle table, you must create in there too.

Once you have created your chain, you link it to the default chains with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j MYCHAIN
```